# Using custom parameters on search with YouTube API in .NET

Tags: .net, youtube-api, youtube.net-api

Some queries, like `OrderBy`, are part of the `YouTubeQuery` class and are easy to set. But the general YouTube API reference mention both [HD](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#hdsp) and [duration](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#durationsp) parameters which I'd really like to use for my app.

Since I'm using the [.NET library for the Google Data API](http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/) I'd prefer to use some built-in method rather than just tack on a query-string to the end of the Uri. Maybe using `YouTubeQuery.ExtraParameters` or something else, but I can't find what that would be.

How do you set the [extra parameters for YouTube API in .NET](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#Custom_parameters)?

Answer (score 1):

Following code works for Java. I am sure equivalent .Net code is similar to this:

```
YouTubeQuery ytQuery = new YouTubeQuery(new URL(API_URL));

ytQuery.addCustomParameter(new Query.CustomParameter("hd", "true"));
ytQuery.addCustomParameter(new Query.CustomParameter("duration", "short"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i found it by myself..You can use the following code to set extraparameters for duration;

query.ExtraParameters = "&duration=medium";